# Invalid Config, Exiting abnormally when launching zookeper from Kafka tutorial

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I'm following this tutorial trying to set up kafka,

https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart

And I get this error when doing the part on zookeeper. 
It certainly has something to do with the config, but I don't understand to what extend.

```
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/server.properties
[2018-03-17 03:27:11,623] INFO Reading configuration from: config/server.properties (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig)
[2018-03-17 03:27:11,628] ERROR Invalid config, exiting abnormally (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain)
org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig$ConfigException: Error processing config/server.properties
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.parse(QuorumPeerConfig.java:154)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.initializeAndRun(QuorumPeerMain.java:101)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.main(QuorumPeerMain.java:78)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "initial.rebalance.delay.ms"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:589)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:631)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.parseProperties(QuorumPeerConfig.java:242)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.parse(QuorumPeerConfig.java:150)
    ... 2 more
Invalid config, exiting abnormally
```

Comment: Use fully qualified name if you are on windows. I was facing same issue but it was resolved when I used fully qualified path for batch file & properties file.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you look closely, you'll notice that the command to start Zookeeper is:

```
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
```

Using the `zookeeper.properties` file.

It looks like you copied the command to start Kafka which is using `server.properties`.

Comment: I do not understand why they use this command if the good one is the one you wrote. It works with your command. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 14):

I fixed this on Windows by doing below.

Make sure to specify full paths.

First, go to the `bin\windows` folder of your kafka installation:

```
C:\kafka_2.12-2.0.0\bin\windows
```

Then, run the following command:

```
.\zookeeper-server-start.bat C:\kafka_2.12-2.0.0\config\zookeeper.properties
```

When done, you will see the following output:

```
[2020-07-06 20:25:13,703] INFO Server environment:user.dir=C:\kafka_2.12-2.0.0\bin\windows (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2020-07-06 20:25:13,716] INFO tickTime set to 3000 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2020-07-06 20:25:13,717] INFO minSessionTimeout set to -1 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2020-07-06 20:25:13,717] INFO maxSessionTimeout set to -1 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2020-07-06 20:25:13,787] INFO Using org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory as server connection factory (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ServerCnxnFactory)
[2020-07-06 20:25:13,791] INFO binding to port 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using following to start the zookeeper:

```
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/server.properties
```

Zookeeper configuration settings are placed in zookeeper.properties file.
So, to start zookeeper:

```
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
```

And for starting KAFKA server:

```
bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
```

Keep in mind which file comes with which server.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing same issue because I am directly giving step2 command in my terminal,which is wrong. We have to run command of step2 in our Kafka folder.
Follow below steps to run zookeeper successfully.

Step1: Goto your kafka folder or simply do cd $KAFKA_HOME

STEP2: bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh ./config/zookeeper.properties

Answer (score 0):

1. check for "dataDir=/tmp/zookeeper1", if not present then create a directory and one file inside this directory myid

```
mkdir -p /tmp/zookeeper1
chmod -R 777 /tmp/zookeeper1
vi /tmp/zookeeper1/myid 
(add value as 1, this is server-id from server.1=)
```

Comment: Hi, I tried to change dataDir from "/tmp/zookeeper" to "/var/lib/zookeeper" which contains a file called myid (didn't alter the text inside though) but the Zookeeper service failed to start with the same error described in the question. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

On Window 10, this command solved this issue for me:

```
C:\kafka_2.13-3.6.0\bin\windows>zookeeper-server-start.bat C:\kafka_2.13-3.6.0\config\zookeeper.properties
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to remove **config/** , and use the file directly.

e.g.

bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh zookeeper.properties